# Is there a difference between 'inconsistent', 'contrary', and 'contradictory'

Tags: logic, terminology, propositional-calculus

Is there a difference between 'inconsistent' 'contrary' and 'contradictory'? As far as I understand, two statements are inconsistent when they can not both be true; two statements are contradictory when they can not both bear the same truth value.

Does 'contrary' have a unique meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A contradiction is an pair of statements of the form $p$ and $\lnot p$.

A set of statements is contradictory if there is a pair of statements in it that form a contradiction.

A set of statements is inconsistent if you can *derive* a contradiction from them.

We will sometimes use the terms "contradiction" and "contradictory" more loosely to mean "obviously inconsistent."

"Contrary" is used informally to mean the negation of a statement. I don't think I've ever seen a set of statements called "contrary," for example, just because there is a contradiction. Perhaps there is a formal use of the term that I am missing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 'Contrary' is used in classical logic. As far as I can tell it means 'inconsistent'. That said, I was surprised to learn of the distinctions between -> and =>. I was hoping a similar distinction might exist between 'contrary' and 'inconsistent' - synonyms seem like a waste to me.  What did you mean by 'derive'; could you give me an example? Thank you.

Comment: Derive means deduce. You can prove two statements that are contradictions.  A simple example would be the two statements $a\land b$ and $\lnot a \lor \lnot b$. These two are not directly contradictions, but you can (quickly) deduce that they are contradictory.  The real case where "inconsistency" comes up is in axiom systems - a set of axioms that are inconsistent are not worth much effort. The point of inconsistency is that it is not necessarily obvious from the list of statements, or even decidable in any computational sense.

Comment: So then, I think that makes the distinction clear. Inconsistency refers to a set of statements from which a contradiction can be derived (a∧b and ¬a∨¬b.), Contradiction is in essence the same, but does not need to be derived (p and ¬p), and contrary is for forms that are only true when all variables are false, like: ((g∧¬b) v (b∧¬g)). Is that possible, or have I made a mistake?

Comment: As I've said, "contrary" is not a term I know, but yes, a contradictory set of statements is essentially "trivially" inconsistent, in that there is a zero-step proof of a contradiction.

Comment: From the Wikipedia article for contrary in logic, a pair of statements are contrary if and only if they are inconsistent. The distinction probably goes back to logic - inconsistency tends to be a word applied about axiom systems, while "contrary" seems more general (and hence older) logic idea. But they amount to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is already an accepted answer that describes the issue pretty well.  To add to it, however, *contrary* and *contradictory* are used with distinct meanings in Aristotelian logic.  The [square of opposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_of_opposition) shows four types of relations between sentences.  These are:

- contrary;
- subcontrary;
- contradictory; and
- subalternation.

Therein, the contrary of the sentence "All S are P" is "No S are P", while its contradictory is "Some S is not P."  The contradictory is logically equivalent to the negation, but the contrary is not.  The linked Wikipedia article covers all the cases in much more detail.  You're probably not likely to encounter these terms in casual use, or even in formal logic today unless someone is making a point of speaking about Aristotelian logic.